# how to load a .html page into another on the click of a button ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, netbeans, event-listener

My application works as expected within Netbeans IDE , how ever when i try to run it locally there are jquery issues.

I have a page with a button id="login" within a div id="main",  when i click this button i wish to load a html page into this div which contains that button, as in i replace all original contents.

This was simply done on netbeans but wont work locally, any ideas ?

```
<div id="main">
    <button id="login" type="button" >Login</button>
</div>
```

and the jquery. ( paths are correct as the browser sees the EventListener )

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#login").click(function () {
        $("#main").load("table.html");
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: does "locally" mean that you are just opening the html file? you have to be running a server to use `$.load();` or to perform any sort of ajax call in general.

Comment: listenerBody: "function ( e ) {↵    // Discard the second event of a jQuery.event.trigger()